# Compressing PNG image programmatically in iOS

Tags: ios

I need to send to server png images with 300DPI and exactly 1275x1875pixels in size. Because by default UIKit will create image with 72DPI, I need to set scale factor to 300/72 in UIKit function [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uikitfunctionreference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) to be able to get 300DPI image, and after this I'm using UIImagePNGRepresentation function to get NSData of image and write it in file. For now I can get desired image size and DPI (have checked in photoshop), but it becomes almost 5mb. Is there any way to reduce PNG image size in iOS?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you need compression, why not send those images as JPEG instead?

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation ( UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality );
```

Set compressionQuality to 0f for highest compression, 1f for lowest.  Convert back to PNG when you need a PNG.

Comment: This is not a solution, because this function makes my image 72DPI, but I need it to be 300DPI

Comment: So convert the jpg to a 300dpi PNG file on the backend.  "DPI" doesn't make a ton of sense in the context you are presenting here.

Comment: Backend is not mine, and it requires 300DPI, so I have to do this in device